# How to access state from callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a component in react native:

```
export default class Screen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prop1: false,
      prop2: simpleFunc
    };
  }
  simpleFunc = () => { /*...*/ }

  componentWillMount() {
      BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', this.onLocation);
```

The last line is callback method that will be called on new location.
From that method I can't access `this.state` or `this.simpleFunc()`.
What should I do in order to update state from callback function?

Comment: Is it because you're using an arrow function?

Comment: On location look like this: `onLocation(location) {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to access `this` inside `onLocation` you need to bind the callback:

```
  componentWillMount() {
      BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', this.onLocation.bind(this));
```

or, you can use an arrow function (which will use the lexical scope of the parent):

```
  componentWillMount() {
      BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', (location) => this.onLocation(location));
```